# How to extract the full row label from Excel PivotTable?

Tags: excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a PivotTable in Excel with multiple layers of row filtering: Month > Region > Product (1 > EU > Dessert). When I mouse over the row, I am able to see the full row label (1 - EU - Dessert):
[pivot row label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EBWL.png)

I know that I can go to PivotTable Tools > Design > Report Layout > Show in Tabular Form and then Repeat All Item Labels and then use a simple formula to get the full row label into a single cell, but I am trying to avoid changing the format of the PivotTable. Ideally, I would like to maintain the formatting of the PivotTable seen in the image above, but extract the full row label (using a formula) from the PivotTable for use in another cell.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like the opposite of GetPivotData: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/getpivotdata-function-8c083b99-a922-4ca0-af5e-3af55960761f
Found a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47212578/extract-pivot-table-row-label-not-value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract Pivot Table Row Label (not value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47212578/extract-pivot-table-row-label-not-value)

Comment: Not exactly. I don't want the names of the literal rows (from the PivotTable fields area) like the author of the previous question wanted. I am looking to effectively extract the full name of the individual record in the table: 1-EU-Dessert